# How to sum a column using after order by and group by

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a table contains agentid, productname, groupname and quantity like

```
Agentid    Productname    Groupname    Quantity

  a1         M1000          Milk          10
  a1         M500           Milk          20
  a1         G500           Ghee          10

  a2         M1000          Milk          20
  a2         M500           Milk          10
  a2         G500           Ghee          30
```

I want to sum up the quantity for every agent like

```
Agentid       Groupname    Quantity

  a1           Milk          30
  a1           Ghee          10

  a2           Milk          30
  a2           Ghee          30
```

Pls somebody help to write the query for this in mysql..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
select Agentid,Groupname, sum(Quantity) 
from table_name 
group by Agentid,Groupname  
order by Agentid,Groupname
```

Comment: This particular order by is redundant

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT Agentid,
       Groupname,
       sum(Quantity) AS Quantity
FROM TABLE_NAME
GROUP BY Agentid, Groupname
ORDER BY Agentid;
```

Comment: Thanks for immediate reply but it gives me only the first agent. But I want the output as I mentioned above

Comment: @user3828319 never forgot to accept answer when answer is useful.

Answer (score 0):

you need to aggregate using `GROUP BY` clause and `SUM()` as the aggregation function. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html

So your query should be something like

```
SELECT Agentid, Groupname, SUM(Quantity)
   FROM table
   GROUP BY Agentid, Groupname
   ORDER BY Agentid
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work :

```
select Agentid,Groupname, SUM(Quantity) 
from tb_name
group by Agentid,Groupname
```

SQLFiddle [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/87402/3)

Comment: Any difference from available answers?

Comment: @Sadikhasan answered with demo.

Comment: Good. It is fine to understand by user